# vue.js update current user data from api when change route?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

im new in vuejs and i build small control panel and i have roles and permissions.

when user login i store data in local storage with user data and he roles and permissions

but when the admin attach or change role or permission for any user

not update in that user if he login even he logout and login again

**my solution is get current user every time from api when route change!**

i put my call function in app.js

```
store.dispatch('users/getUser');
```

is that good solution ?

Comment: Where are you storing the user in local storage, in mutations? Can you add the code for that part

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana in local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not store profile and permissions in localStorage as user could inspect it and modify it.

I think you should store user id encrypted and in each route change validate if he as permission for the desired page or action.

So essentially yes but don’t forget about security.

Comment: I agree about security. So if the data is just used to display to the current user their role and permissions then this is fine. It would be insecure to rely on this to enforce any type of role/permissions. In that case anything on the client would be insecure.

Comment: @damil Yes i use vuex-persistedstate to secure state data, and i really do that to get current user data with token.  
**Damil** your idea its good.